# How to define a fix sequence of MNIST training images with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, mnist

I try to train a model with TensorFlow and the MNIST dataset from the TensorFlow examples. That works fine.
But everytime i start my python script which run the model training there is a different order (sequence) of the training images.
How can i define that the sequence of training images is everytime the same, when i start my python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) you will have some code in your script that looks something like this:

```
for _ in range(1000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)   
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
```

The function next_batch is defined [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py) In the definition,

```
 def next_batch(self, batch_size, fake_data=False, shuffle=True):
```

you will see that the keyword argument shuffle defaults to True. So try changing your call to next_batch to include shuffle=False as below.

```
batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100, shuffle=False)
```

Without a minimal example of the actual script you are trying to use it will be difficult to provide more info.